# How to change task affinity in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recents, taskaffinity

There is an activity (A) in my application that can be called from other apps (B)

if A is called from B, in recent task there are an instance of B and an instance of A. i want that A be showen as part of B Task.

I've found that by adding same `taskAffinity` to both activities manifest file it works as i want. but i can't access B.

```
android:taskAffinity="xxx.yyy"
```

so, how do i find affinity of task B and change affinity of task A to it? OR is there a better way?

Comment: `"i want that A be showen as part of B Task."` in recent tasks only the tasks are shown, not particular activities

Comment: @pskink thats why i want A have same task as B

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/components/recents.html

Answer (score 0):

Since [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) is required for [taskAffinity](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) to take effect (that is, place activity A in a different task), start Activity A without using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`. I think this will cause activity A to be in the same task as activity B. This requires a change to B.